# Error compiling project with NodeJs and Gulp

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, gulp, node-modules

I'm running the mvn clean install command to compile my project which is made with java in the backend and angular in the front.
I do this on Linux normally but I'm configuring the environment on windows and I'm getting errors

Error

```
[10:52:34] Starting '<anonymous>'...
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\git\java\flextotal\src\main\webapp\build'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
[10:52:34] '<anonymous>' errored after 45 ms
[10:52:34] Error: 1
    at formatError (D:\git\java\flextotal\src\main\webapp\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\format-error.js:21:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (D:\git\java\flextotal\src\main\webapp\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\log\events.js:33:15)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at Gulp.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at Object.error (D:\git\java\flextotal\src\main\webapp\node_modules\undertaker\lib\helpers\createExtensions.js:61:10)
    at handler (D:\git\java\flextotal\src\main\webapp\node_modules\now-and-later\lib\mapSeries.js:47:14)
    at f (D:\git\java\flextotal\src\main\webapp\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at f (D:\git\java\flextotal\src\main\webapp\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at tryCatch (D:\git\java\flextotal\src\main\webapp\node_modules\async-done\index.js:24:15)
    at done (D:\git\java\flextotal\src\main\webapp\node_modules\async-done\index.js:40:12)
[10:52:34] 'cliBuildProd' errored after 83 ms
[10:52:34] 'copyReleaseBundles' errored after 89 ms
[10:52:34] 'buildRelease' errored after 90 ms
[10:52:34] '<anonymous>' errored after 91 ms
[10:52:34] 'default' errored after 92 ms
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! flextotal@1.0.0 build:release: `gulp --release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the flextotal@1.0.0 build:release script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

My Gulp File

```
process.setMaxListeners(Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
const cp = require('child_process');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const del = require('del');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');
const plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
const tslint = require("tslint");
const gulpMultiProcess = require('gulp-multi-process');
const fs = require('fs');


const debug = process.argv.indexOf("--development") > -1;
const useAot = !debug; // constante usada para testes sem AOT
console.log("debug: " + debug);

const ngBuildArgs = ['build', '--deploy-url', 'dist/'];
const ngBuildArgsProd = [...ngBuildArgs, '--prod', '--extract-licenses', 'false'];
// o cli não está gerando os paths corretos sem usar extract-css
const ngBuildArgsDebug = [...ngBuildArgs];
const ngBuildArgsWatch = [...ngBuildArgsDebug, '--watch', '--no-delete-output-path', '--progress', 'false'];

if (debug) {
    var localConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./local-config.json'));
    if (!localConfig.deployPath) {
        throw new Error("deployPath não definido no local-config.json");
    }
    if (!localConfig.applicationUrl) {
        throw new Error("applicationUrl não definido no local-config.json");
    }
}

// workaround pra remover reflect do build aot
// https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6325
gulp.task('processPolyfills', gulp.series(function() {
    return gulp.src("app/polyfills." + (debug ? "development" : "production") + ".ts")
        .pipe(plugins.rename("polyfills.ts"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("app/"));
}));


gulp.task('clean', (done) => {
    del.sync(['./app.jsp', 'dist/**/*', 'dist-aot']);
    done();
});

function copyAppJsp() {
    const html = fs.readFileSync('./dist-aot/index.html', 'utf-8');
    fs.writeFileSync('app.jsp', html);
    if (debug) {
        fs.writeFileSync(localConfig.deployPath + 'app.jsp', html);
    }
}

gulp.task('compileDebug', gulp.series(['processPolyfills'], function(cb) {
    const ng = cp.spawn(process.execPath, ngBuildArgsDebug, { stdio: 'inherit' });
    ng.on('close', code => cb(code));
}));

gulp.task('copyDebugBundles', gulp.series(['compileDebug'], function() {
    copyAppJsp()
    return gulp.src(['dist-aot/**/*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
}));

gulp.task('startNgWatch', gulp.series(['processPolyfills'], function(done) {
    // criamos o diretório antes pois o watch não funciona com diretórios
    // inexistentes (que serão criados no ng build, e não tem como verificar quando)
    fs.mkdirSync('dist-aot');

    cp.spawn(process.execPath, ngBuildArgsWatch, { stdio: 'inherit' });
    done();
}));

gulp.task('multiProcessBundle', gulp.series(function(cb) {
    // por padrão o node executa tudo na mesma thread,
    // este plugin usa child_process pra torná-lo multi processo
    return gulpMultiProcess(['lint'], cb);
}));


gulp.task('watch', gulp.series(['clean', 'startNgWatch', 'multiProcessBundle'], function() {
    let firstFile = true;
    // plugin utilizado porque o watch padrão do gulp não detecta criação de arquivos
    return plugins.watch('dist-aot/**/*', { readDelay: 500 })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(localConfig.deployPath + 'dist'))
        .pipe(plugins.tap(function(file) {
            if (file.path.endsWith("/index.html")) {
                copyAppJsp();
            }

            if (firstFile) {
                firstFile = false;
                browserSync.init({
                    proxy: localConfig.applicationUrl,
                    browser: localConfig.browser,
                    ghostMode: false,
                    reloadDebounce: 500
                });
            } else {
                browserSync.reload(file);
            }
        }));
}));





gulp.task('lint', gulp.series(function() {
    var program = tslint.Linter.createProgram("./tsconfig.json");
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(plugins.tslint({
            program: program
        }))
        .pipe(plugins.tslint.report({
            allowWarnings: true
        }));
}))

gulp.task('cliBuildProd', gulp.series(['processPolyfills'], function(cb) {
    const ng = cp.spawn(process.execPath, ngBuildArgsProd, { stdio: 'inherit' });
    ng.on('close', code => cb(code));
}));

gulp.task('copyReleaseBundles', gulp.series(['cliBuildProd'], function() {
    copyAppJsp()
    return gulp.src(['dist-aot/**/*', '!dist-aot/index.html'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
}));



gulp.task('_test', gulp.series(gulp.parallel(['clean', 'copyDebugBundles', 'multiProcessBundle']), function(cb) {
    const ng = cp.spawn(process.execPath, ['test', '--single-run'], { stdio: 'inherit' });
    ng.on('close', code => cb(code));
}));

gulp.task('buildDebug', gulp.series(gulp.parallel(['clean', 'copyDebugBundles', 'multiProcessBundle']), function() {
    return del(['dist-aot']);
}));

gulp.task('buildRelease', gulp.series(gulp.parallel(['clean', 'copyReleaseBundles', 'multiProcessBundle']), function() {
    return del(['dist-aot']);
}));

gulp.task('test', gulp.series('_test', function() {
    return del(['dist-aot']);
}));

function runTaskIf(condition, task) {
    task = gulp.series(task) // make sure we have a function that takes callback as first argument
    return function(cb) {
        if (condition()) {
            task(cb)
        } else {
            cb()
        }
    }
}

isDebug = function() {
    return debug;
}
isRelease = function() {
    return !debug;
}


gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel([
    runTaskIf(isDebug, 'buildDebug'),
    runTaskIf(isRelease, 'buildRelease')
]));
```

Something seems to have changed in Windows compared to Linux
However, I redid the environment with the same version for all installations

I would be grateful if anyone could shed some light on this matter.

I tried changes in the Gulp file and also tried deleting the package-lock.json folder and the NodeModules folder and running npm install again
but without success

Comment: Why does this have the java tag?

Comment: As I mentioned my project is java, that's why I put it too, I don't know if it can involve

Comment: Java is not involved here, though maybe Maven is.